# How to generate and send contribution history to each Donor

Tags: civireport, receipts, cdn-tax-receipts

Civicrm 5.57  Wordpress 6.1.1

Hello,

Here is the scenario: We have 100 donors whose employers agreed to match their donation total for the last year.  We need to generate the donation history for each of these people for the year of 2022 and send each individual their own history

Is there a way to generate these histories and email them with tokenx to the group in civimail? Or is the only way to generate each individual receipt and send it to each person on by one?

Thank you

Comment: may be worth pointing out that sending folk to their civicrm dashboard is one way of letting them see their donor history in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transactions tokens](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/transactionstokens) might be useful to you?

Comment: Thank you. We just installed it and so far no errors. We will test and see how well it works.   Now we wish there was a way we could select a date range of contributions the tokens would pull.  We can only use transactions from February to December 31st.  Do you have suggestions for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, custom date is available on the Print/Merge document, will need some funding to add it on email forms

Comment: It’s working fine. Thank you. We did have to delete the contributions from January 2022 because we didn’t become a 501c3 until February. But that is okay and we won’t have that issue next year.  This is a great extension you developed